# How should I mask when spraying trim?

Tags: paint, trim

I am getting ready to spray the trim in my house using a 211 tip.  How much of each room needs to be masked or do I just need to mask everything (except the trim)?

Answer (score 4):

My first question is why are you planning on spraying trim in a completed house? (windows, door trim, base boards, crowns) I could understand maybe spraying out trim in new construction before the  finished floors are installed and walls are not painted yet. You are going to have to cover everything including the furniture! Every edge is going to have to be taped and all hardware has to come off or get masked The second item that comes to mind is that you will have to use a bunch of Flowtrol to shoot a semi-gloss paint thru a 211 tip. You may also want to back brush to get an even finish and avoid "orange peel".  I really think it would be faster and easier to use a good Purdy sash brush and paint your trim the old fashion way, one stroke at a time.

Comment: I bought a foreclosure and the previous owner did this.  Sprayed everything: trim, cabinets, ceilings.  Awful to deal with now.  It was wood grain and sealed and he used to primer.  Thanks guy.  Even if it is taped and masked well, you are gonna get overspray in places you would never think, including the HVAC.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I was only considering this because the house is completely empty.  We just bought it and we are painting the trim and some rooms before we move in.